# How to get the object's name inside a object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Just imagine I have a nested object like the following one:

```
{
    "post":{
        "hello":{
            // what's in here doesn't matter
        }
        "test":{
            // also doesn't matter
        }
}
```

and is there any way to get the object name inside post to an array like this:

```
["hello", "test"]
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj.post)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [`Object.keys(a.post)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhuazNp4PVAhWDuI8KHTH2CbAQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw)

```js
var a = {
    "post": {
      "hello": {
        // what's in here doesn't matter
      },
      "test": {
        // also doesn't matter
      },
    }
}
    console.log(Object.keys(a.post))
```